# I need a PowerShell script to Enumerate Sites, Sub-sites,Lists and document libraries and print them in a .csv file (SP 2007)

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, pnp-powershell

Does anyone have or know a tool or a powershell script/tool i can user to get the full site structure of a SharePoint 2007 site?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tool which we used for SharePoint 2007.

http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/22762